Struggling to retain mathematical knowledge as a self-learner.
I’m a self-learner who studies mathematics because of a deep passion for the subject. However, I’ve been facing a persistent issue that has started to seriously affect both my progress and motivation, I also realised that I don't know how to effectively self-study. The problem is that I  frequently  forget much of what I’ve learned  Completely, especially when revisiting topics after a break (like two or three month). For example, I’ve gone through substantial portions of real analysis multiple times, but every time I return to it, I feel like I’m encountering the material for the first time. This cycle of relearning and forgetting is preventing me from moving forward in my studies, and it’s making me feel stuck.
The biggest issue is that when I try to move forward to more advanced topics, I realize that they often rely on concepts I’ve already studied but completely forgotten. Then, I need to go back to review the previous material, but even that leads me to realize I’ve forgotten even earlier prerequisites. It’s a never-ending chain of going backwards to relearn foundational concepts, which leaves me stuck. The idea of having to completely relearn multiple layers of topics before moving forward feels overwhelming and exhausting.
Here are the specific struggles I’m dealing with:

Knowing when to move on: Since I study alone, I don’t have anyone to guide me on when it’s appropriate to move on to the next topic. How do I judge whether I’ve truly learned something well enough to progress to more advanced topics? Sometimes I feel like I need to perfectly memorize every detail before moving forward, but that seems impossible, and I’m not sure if that’s the right approach.
What to focus on retaining or memorize:  I struggle with what kind of knowledge I should aim to retain long-term. Should I be memorizing theorems, definitions, and proofs in full detail, or is it enough to understand their general purpose? For example, I can often remember why a theorem was introduced or what it’s used for, but I can’t always recall the exact statement or proof. This is especially true for theorems with lengthy proofs, like the implicit function theorem. Should I be able to remember these in detail, or is it more important to have a conceptual understanding? This uncertainty adds to my frustration, as I don’t know if I’m focusing on the wrong things.
Forgetting key concepts: I feel particularly frustrated when I realize that I’ve forgotten key concepts, even after studying them thoroughly. It’s discouraging to go back to material like real analysis and find that I can barely remember important definitions or the reasoning behind proofs. I know it’s normal to forget details over time, but I’m wondering if there are strategies to minimize this. How do you retain what you’ve learned, especially when you’re not using it regularly? Should I be reviewing past material in a certain way to make sure it sticks, or is there another technique that could help?
Boredom of repeating the same thing: When I forget a part (not the whole) of a chapter, subject, or section, I tend to spend more time revising it than I did when learning it the first time. This happens because the repetition leads to boredom, and as a result, I lose concentration more easily. That made me wonder: How do you revise a subject effectively without losing focus? Should I also redo every problem in that part?

I feel like I’m drowning in this struggle that also made my love and passion for math decrease, also I wonder everyday am I the only one who struggles with this? Am I good enough? , and it’s weighing on me heavily and I’m starting to feel deeply discouraged. I’m passionate about math and want to continue learning, but this obstacle is making it difficult to move forward. I don’t have access to real-life guidance, so I’m reaching out to this community for advice.
What strategies do you use to retain mathematical knowledge over the long term, and how do you balance learning new material with reviewing old topics? Any guidance or suggestions would be incredibly helpful.

I realize this question might be closed, but I’m truly in need of guidance and would be grateful if someone could still help, even in the comments. I don’t have anyone to guide me in my learning, and I’m feeling lost and helpless right now. I know some of you are professors or experienced learners, so your advice would mean the world to me. Please, if you can, help me find a way forward. Thank you so much.

Robert Oppenheimer: "There is no better way to learn than to teach". Try to organize and summarize whatever you are learning and teach/explain to another person. In the absence of a human victim, one can always do that to a rubber duck.

It sounds like your approach might be too memorization-oriented. Things are easier to remember the more deeply you understand them. Take your time and ask yourself what the topic is about and what the theorems are doing. If you have a clearer big-picture view, it's easier to see how the pieces fit together.

@Karl I don't know how to study math see "What to focus on retaining" part in the question

@achillehui I don't know what to retain

I understand this question might be closed, but I would really appreciate it if someone could still provide an answer, even in the comments. I know some of you are professors or experienced learners, and your advice would mean a lot to me. Thank you in advance!

i just hope that this question doesn't get closed...

Self-learning is tough. As a professor of 40 years or so, I always assigned and graded substantial and challenging homework. In my view, students learn only by wrestling with homework (some routine, but plenty not) and getting and internalizing the feedback they get on that homework. With self-learning, this whole part of the process tends to be missing.

@TedShifrin How can I replace it?

You of course have to do lots of exercises, not just read textbooks. But the trouble is that with non-computational homework (such as real analysis) it's very hard to know if you've done it correctly. In my experience, students' proof-writing skills are developed only with feedback. Of course, lots of people in your position post questions on this site that amount to asking for that feedback. You just need to be judicious and specific in the questions that you post. That said, you do have to sit down and master definitions as you go.

Try solving lots of exercises as you learn. This tends to help remembering things.

If you can find a way of discussing with other people who are leaning at the same time, that also tends to help.

@TedShifrin how to get these exercises ? I solve most of the exercises  provided by the book I use but eventually I forget them.

@ManuelAraújo No one in my friends or family care about math, I am the only one who cares about it in my social group apparently, I study math alone in my cave (room).

After my school days I self-studied many mathematical topics and in my opinion self study works best for topics which interest you. Try not to study everything.

@ParamanandSingh How did you manage to remember what you learned, Do you forget the proofs or some theorems, and how you deal with that? Also let's say you are interested in algebraic topology but as you know there are not many applications for it so you won't use it very often, after a couple of months was out revising it or revisiting it you will probably forget a lot of proofs and after couple of years you will forget the whole course.

I do tend to forget complicated formulas, but the proofs are easier to handle. If you understand a proof well enough you won't forget it. Especially the proofs of fundamental theorems in any topic must be well understood. This requires going over proofs again and again as many times as necessary. However I can expect one to forget very long proofs in a span of few years. Even then for long proofs one may remember its outline and miss the details.

Great question! I am interested in writing an answer to this as well myself :) Thank you for sharing your experiences - it can be quite intimidating to ask such questions! And thank you to everyone who has commented/answered on this thread!

@stats_noob I am waiting to see your answer.

@pie: Just posted an answer today

Some advice which I hope may help. In terms of learning the topic:

Flashcards: When you are learning a particular topic, consider what definitions, lemmas, or theorems are the most prudent. I recommend using something like Anki, which is focused on spaced repetition.
Proof notebook: Proofs are an important part of mathematics. When you are going through a topic, it’s useful to think about which proofs are of particular importance, and write these up in a nice notebook. Perhaps these are the proofs which unite together various concepts, or highlights the importance of the topic. Writing these up in a notebook means that you can flick through this notebook every so often and refresh your mind.
Key concepts folder: When you learn a topic, it can be a good measure of deep understanding to try simplifying the topic down. I like to take one or two sheets of A4 paper and summarise the entire topic onto this. Keep all of these in a folder for your various mathematical endeavours, and then you can flick through it to remember what the key parts.
Teaching: The ability to teach a subject is a good measure of understanding. Perhaps you can design a few pretend lectures on the topic. Write down a little plan, stand in front of your chalkboard, and teach. While you’re doing this think of potential questions a student might have.
Problems, problems, problems: Problems are such a big part of mathematics. The ability to work through various problems pertaining to a topic is an important act. If it’s a topic you’re struggling with, start with easy problems, and then as you improve, go on to more difficult ones. This is also important because it allows you to see connections with other parts of mathematics, as various concepts from other topics will undoubtedly be a necessary part of these problems.
Forge connections: Forging connections is a useful exercise. When you’re learning a new topic, it’s important to think how it links with others, considering its relations to different concepts. Perhaps you make a diagram to represent this.

As for how to know when to move on, there isn’t really a definite answer. For example, if you are self studying something, then there is far more freedom in when to move on, whereas if you are at university with time constraints, this may be before you like. A few potential assessments of when to move on:

Comfort with key concepts: Do you feel confident in stating key definitions, theorems, and lemmas?
Understanding the topic: Could you explain large parts of the topic to someone else?
Varied problems: Can you solve problems in the topic? Are you able to work through more difficult problems?
Forging connections: Can you see how this topic links to others? Are you able to forge connections?

I hope this helps! If you’d like me to elaborate on any point, let me know.

the "Key concepts folder:" part I tried it but ended up copying the text book

@pie I think the key concepts folder works best like this: read a chapter or section of the textbook without writing down anything - consult multiple resources if needed. Doodle, go through examples, go through exercises. Only when you feel that you have a sense of the topic should you write anything for the folder. The key thing you’re thinking of when you write down the key concepts is - how can I summarise this entire topic into a page of A4? What’s important? What diagrams may help?

pie, it is probably hard to remember material if you don't use them. I think it's okay when you learn something more advanced, that you realise you haven't learned a prerequisite well and then go back to go through the prerequisite. You don't have to chastise yourself that you have forgotten the prerequisite. Sometimes it's even possible to have written a research article, and then after many years look at it and think to yourself "oh, so I wrote this?". So do keep on learning, and if you find you need to revise, just gently go back and learn the basic material again.
As for knowing when to move on to the next topic, it depends on what is your goal of learning. Generally, math can be divided into knowledge and technique. To master a technique, you must know how to use it. As for knowledge, you remember the facts, but it's okay to refer back to printed material and check your memory. It's not possible to fully understand an area, so it depends on your goal. If you goal is to understand a theorem and its proof, then you need to know enough prerequisite knowledge to at least understand what the theorem is stating. If you goal is to use a certain technique, then you need to know the basic facts of the area and do exercises to see if you can apply the technique.
As time passes, you may be able to digest what you learned. Sometimes concepts like category theory can be used to capture what you have learned in a succinct form. For example, you may learn that every vector space has a basis. Then, say over a field $K$, category theory can say that the functor from the category whose objects are the natural numbers and whose morphism from a natural number $n$ to a natural number $m$ is a $m \times n$ matrix to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces that sends a natural number $n$ to $K^n$ and a matrix $A$ to the linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax$ is an equivalence of categories.

pie, I recognize a lot of myself in your description. Well, except for the self-study aspect, I studied at a university (but then again, after finished formal studies part of a mathematicians life is self-studies, most of us never get finished with learning).
I too am in the habit of forgetting at least the finer details of what I once learned, especially if I have not used it for a period. People are different, and while I can feel envy toward those who seem to remember everything they learnt, I think it is important to accept one's individual treats and work out strategies using one's strengths instead of trying to shoehorn oneself into a misfitting strategy.
I agree with earlier posters that you seem to put a bit to much emphasize on memorizing; understanding is MUCH more important (and makes remembering at least parts of the stuff easier). I did that exact error myself the first year of my university studies, but somehow came to the realization that I needed to focus more on understanding. I doubt very much that I would have succeeded getting a PhD in pure math with my early, memorizing based, study tactics. And an important part on focusing on understanding is not only reading math but doing it. And by doing I don't only mean doing standard exercises but also reflect on why: why using this method here, why is that concept defined in the way it is, and so on. You might not always find an answer, but the times you do will most likely help you remember things. Thing and aspects discovered are usually easier to remember than things learned by reading, unfortunately.
All this is probably more easily said than done, especially as you are self-studying. Lack of guidance and support IS a disadvantage. I don't know why you are self-studying, but have you considered attending web-based courses? I would recomend trying that, if it is possible and you haven't already, just to see what effect guidance and support would have for you, not least regarding your second question.


I don't know why you are self-studying

I like math, I want to be a mathematician but math in my country is very poor also the education is very bad so my only choice is to study it alone, unless there is a university that want a math geek and nerd and is obsessed with math for another country

This answer is partial. I shall share my experience about the lack of memory and guidance, but I think you have to find your way to study.
Welcome! Forgetfulness of scientists is reflected in anecdotes. My boss, Taras Banakh, once wrote an article twice because he forgot that he had already written it. But I agree that forgetting often can be a real problem. My bad memory was one of the reasons why I chose mathematics over other subjects, for instance, over history. If I forget a mathematical fact, for instance, a theorem then I can reprove (or, at least, reconstruct) it. However, if I forget a historical fact, for instance, the battle year, then I am lost, especially because I did not care about the battle sides and causes.
But the problem remains even after the choice. For instance, I have to check a book on simple trigonometric or even exponential identities, have to reconstruct the usual values of trigonometric functions, and sometimes I have problems even with the multiplication table. The reason for that is if I want to be completely rigorous then I cannot trust my bad memory. I guess I have an obsessive–compulsive disorder.
I tend to replenish memory lack by libraries and personal archives. If a book is good then it is a pleasure to read it once more, and this experience can be more advanced if you become that. I think it
can provide spiral development instead of circular walking.
So, my generic solution to the forgetting problem is to care not about memory but about mind brightness, clarity and strength. I think this choice also makes me more living in present and concentrates my efforts on current practice, that is promoted by Eastern teachings, especially by Buddhism. I think it makes the mind/vision more fresh, bright, clear, easy, and open.
But my solution is one-sided, and I am not sure that it is perfect for everybody. If your forgetfulness is a disaster and spreads far beyond mathematics then maybe a good idea is to discuss it with a psychologist and ask for help if needed.

I study math alone in my cave.

I would be happy to live such a life.
I prefer to study in a natural and mind-friendly way and I definitely do not want to be guided. So I just read that I understand and that is interesting to me. The mind is a great thing and it completes the rest. Although now I am already a mature mathematician, when I wasted my time for the formal education, I proceeded similarly, so I missed almost all mathematical lessons. I wish I devoted all my time from the formal education to mathematical reading and writing. Although I think that most mathematical professors are nice people and many are clever, but books are much better to study, so I prefer books to any university. The latter has several drawbacks. For instance, I have a lot of freedom to choose a book and its reading style and tempo according to my level, mood, and amount of free time, but I cannot adjust a university lesson, so it can be too slow or too fast, too simple or too hard, too detailed or too brief, too familiar of too abstract (in my case they usually were too weak). Also, I expect that books are more error-checked, accurate, and detailed than lessons.
As a result of my way, as a mathematician I am formed mainly by reading (from recreational mathematics up to research papers), solving problems (from simple observations, exercises, mathematical puzzles, school competitions to long-standing open problems), and writing papers (and answers at Mathematics StackExchange), and by thinking and understanding. I remark that although I solved a horde of problems, I think this is my way, and if one does not like or does not want to solve problems then one does not have to do this to be a mathematician.

As someone with a learning disability, learning math is very difficult for me.
From a philosophical perspective, I was always interested in the idea of Statistics and Probability - as a child, I would often be troubled by questions such as "how can I be certain that my parents won't forget to pick me up after school?" or "how can I be sure that there is no elephant standing outside the room?".  I remember imaging different scenarios in which my parents might forget to pick me up from school (e.g. an elephant crushed their car)  and soon realized that there are an infinite number of such scenarios that could theoretically take place between the time my parents dropped me at school and the time at which class ends - perhaps it was not just a single elephant, but an entire herd of elephants?
During the school recess or on the back of a coloring notebook - I would then begin to enumerate, analyze and account for each one of these scenarios and would begin to feel claustrophobic and develop a feeling of aversion towards school. What are the chances that I will sleep tonight in an orphanage? If this is the case - how much of my lunch should I set aside and ration for later in case there is no dinner at the orphanage tonight? Or the night after that one as well? The torment is endless.
Though at the time I was not able to fully grasp and reason these concepts, I remember coming to the conclusion that "there do in fact exist an infinite number scenarios in which my parents may not pick me up from school - but the likelihood of most of these scenarios occurring is so small that it's better not to spend time thinking about them and enjoy the time at school".
Thus, as I continued to attend school each day and observed that my parents never forgot to pick me up, I was able to slowly cast away my doubts on these scenarios and begin to enjoy my early education. However, I will never forget my early and very natural encounters with the ideas of Probability and Statistics, and how these "probabilistic calculations" allowed me to stop worrying and start enjoying school. This was just one of the few stories about my relationships and gratitude towards Probability and Statistics.
As I got older, there was a period of my life where I became completely uninterested in math. However, eventually it crept back into my life. The Chilean poet Pablo Neruda once wrote a poem that said "I loved her, and sometimes, she loved me too". Not to sound cliche, but this has always been my relationship with math. I am deeply drawn towards it, but simply awful at understanding even basic things in math. I am both ashamed and proud to say that it took me just over 10 years to accept in my mind that mathematical induction is a valid method to prove things in math ... I would always fail to see how the method of mathematical induction could be a valid proof, as in my mind it was "double dipping" when proving the general case.
I don't know where I am doing with this ... I am bad at so many aspects of math: manipulations, recognizing parts of a problem, logic ... but I think the one thing I am somewhat OK at is mathematical creativity ... how to view real world problems as mathematical concepts. The limited success I have had in this has always served as inspiration to keep pushing in my studies. I have long accepted that in this lifetime, I will not understand mathematics as most people in a university class do ... at first this was very depressing ... but then with the years, this actually became ironically very liberating. Once I realized this, just like Albert Camus' "Myth of Sisyphus", in this moment I become free ... because in a certain way I already know my outcome. Realizing this, I can try as hard as I want and still make progress in my own way ... and still have fun doing math! What I am trying to say is, you can still enjoy playing tennis even if you will never be a pro. Actually, you can still enjoy watching hockey even if you don't know how to skate! :)
On some more tangible notes, I think with time, things get better. Just constantly struggling and studying math everyday slowly makes you better. And I look back at myself 5 years ago and today I think I am a complete different person. One of the main tools that has helped me study and improve at math is the math.stackexchange community. There are so many wonderful mathematicians and educators on this website - and there are so many wonderful people who took the courage to ask questions on this website, that help so many other wonderful people!
I remember in my university asking a professor a question one time ... and my professor was dumbfounded at this question. He said that this is such an obvious point, it doesn't even need to be stated. In that moment, he realized, that perhaps this is an obvious point for him! And not for the average student. Later he spoke to me to get more insights about the question I asked. He wanted to know how I thought of this question, what my intuition was, etc. He wanted to understand the mindset of the average student to see where there difficulties are - are then focus on teaching those difficulties. He then gave me a very nice complement and told me "I am a very good question asker":)
And this is exactly what I try to do in this website. I try to ask informative questions from the mind of an average student that clearly outlines the roadblocks that I experience, while fully detailing what exactly I don't understand and what my intuition is . And even though I might never even publish a single paper in math, I hope that somewhere in the world a student might come across my questions, and simply help them when they are stuck on a problem!
That's all I had to say! Don't give up my friend! I am struggling and studying by your side! :)

I will say two simple things here, also inspired by some comments :
In addition to your personal practice of maths, share and interacts with others in many ways possible :

Courses
Conferences
Games
Tournament
IRL and Online Forum

The interactivity with other humans, also is what make maths a living discipline with a profund purpose. In history, from Pythagore to Poincaré, mathematicians have always been exchanging with their homologues, discussing, putting in perspective maths.
Also, it is important for me to put maths in the perspective of philosophy and of physics and engineering, and all sciences using maths, especially the use of stats in scientific paper is very interesting because the notion of proof in medecine e.g. is arbitrary when you use statistic theorem of real math to build a scientific result.
In conclusion, putting math in the perspective of social interaction and of course other disciplines is for me the way to learn, not linearly yes, but like the water is not a solid and straight element, it remains one of the most powerful and rich on this planet, source of life and evolution.
Be your practice of math as water, or as sais Bruce Lee : "Be water my friend". This is real attitude and content towards math, not just stucking to concepts but, back and forth, exploring other related contents.
